# How extract information using json from api

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this API :

```
{"ID":[{"name":"tuos","tier":"v","queue":"solo"}]}
```

And i need to extract "tier" value from it, i got this code :

```
$result = file_get_contents('URL LINK HERE');
$tier = json_decode($result);
echo $tier->ID->tier;
```

What i need to correct in my code ? and what was wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

That value is in an array (ID is an array as noted by the bracket syntax):

```
echo $tier->ID[0]->tier;
```

Comment: i think it work fine, but i got this error : Cannot access empty property.

Comment: [This code works](https://eval.in/307218). Make sure the data you are getting back from the API is valid.

Comment: Yes it work, can you please check why this one didnt work: https://eval.in/private/f7d73e332eb852

Comment: That's a private link. I can't view it.

Comment: Ah, you're dynamically building your varibale. Try [this](https://eval.in/307231)

Comment: Works, but i still get problem, there is my full code : https://eval.in/307238 (didnt work well in eval.in cos of https but u can see the code)

Comment: You need to show the json you get back. Or, better yet, put it right into the json_decode() function. If it works than you know you need to debug your api call.

Comment: Can you see the link to the api and tell me if i need to debug or something else for it please ?